# How to insert static values in wpf datagrid comboBox column?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

Hi guys i am working with wpf `Datagrid` ,i need to have a `datagridcomboBox` column and i need to have some static values in that column .I have tried following way but the data inside column is not displaying.

```
              <DataGrid
                    Grid.Row="4"
                    Height="200"
                    Width="500"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Margin="10,10,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding SSID}"
                    >

                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="Network ID" Binding="{Binding _networkID}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="SSID" Binding="{Binding _ssid}"/>
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="100" Header="Profile/Groups" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding _apProfiles}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

---

```
public List<string> _apProfiles = new List<string>()
       {
            "21-ARC1000MAP , Indoor Radio b/g/n",
             "22-ARC2000MAP , Dual Radio a/n, b/g/n"
       };
```

Kindly guide me how to solve this issue.Any help would be greatly appreciable.

Comment: is datagridcomboBox column only not displaying values?

Comment: yes only datagridcomboBox column is not displaying values

Comment: The other columns are displaying data perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the datagridcomboboxcolumn itemssource.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="100" Header="Profile/Groups" ItemsSource="{Binding   _apProfiles}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the data context for the datagrid, the columns within the datagrid will look for data within the data context of datagrid. If the value you are binding to datagridcomboBox column is not within the (SSID) the data context of datagrid, you should use,

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="100" Header="Profile/Groups" ItemsSource="{Binding _apProfiles,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
```

or like this

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="100" Header="Profile/Groups" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext. _apProfiles}" />
```

hope this helps.

Comment: What should i replace at `x:Type UserControl` ?

Comment: it can be page or window or usercontrol, see the first sentence of xaml code.

Comment: no combobox column is still freeze nothing is displaying :(

Comment: Is _apProfiles within SSID?

Comment: _apProfiles is in another class !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58768/discussion-between-codesniper-and-selva).